# LeanTween | Rect Transform Moving To Incorrect Position

Tags: unity, tweening

I am using LeanTween to animate my menu selector.

This is how is looked prior to animating it with LeanTween:
[image]

And when I animate it with Leantween, for some reason it is positioned much further away:
[image]

Logic:

First I am starting the tween, and I am passing the RectTransform next to each skill when the player pressed up or down.

```
public void AnimateSubMenuSelector()
    {
        var xPos = MyRectTransform.localPosition.x;
        LeanTween.moveX(MyRectTransform, xPos - 25f, .5f).setLoopPingPong();
    }

public override void SetAssignedRectTransform(RectTransform rectTransform)
    {
        AssignedPosition = rectTransform.position;

    }
```

Then I update the Selector's position every frame with its current x position and it's assigned y position.

```
public override void UpdatePosition()
    {
       
MyRectTransform.position = new Vector2 (MyRectTransform.position.x, AssignedPosition.y) ;
    }
```

It animates correctly, and it moves to the correct y position of the hovered skill, but I don't understand why it's x position is moved so far to the left.

Is anyone that is familiar with LeanTween able to assist me? Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: Did you mean to use AnchoredPosition rather than position/localPosition for moving UI objects?

Comment: Hi Douglas!

Unfortunately, I don't think using AnchoredPosition as opposed to position/localPosition is the answer here.

Though, I did try it either way! It doesn't seem to resolve the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late but I had this issue, and the problem was that I was using the Gameobject variable and not the RectTransform variable as the first argument.

So instead of doing this

```
LeanTween.moveX(gameObject, xPos, .5f);
```

You use the RectTransform component instead like so;

```
LeanTween.moveX(gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), xPos, .5f);
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Note that you can use `(RectTransform)transform` instead of calling `GetComponent` — Unity implements a fast path for getting `Transform` components because they're needed so often.

Comment: @DMGregory oh wow, thanks. I didn't know you could to that with the `Transform` component.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve your issue, but I was already using RectTransform when this issue occurred. My guess is that updating the UI's position every frame along with animating it with LeanTween is what caused the issue to occur for me.